# Creating lines in graphics

Tags: graphics

It is a question very easy, but I am confused how to use the `Table` or `Riffle` or `Partition` to achieve this result.

```
data = {{0, 0}, {228.9, 0.06}, {313.7, 0.10}, {340.6, 0.14}, {355.1, 
    0.18}, {368.2, 0.22}};
lPlot = ListPlot[data, Joined -> True];
pt = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point[Table[data[[#]] &[Range[Length[data]]], 1]]}];
lines = Graphics[{Dashed, Line[{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}], 
    Line[{{228.9, 0}, {228.9, 0.06}}], 
    Line[{{313.7, 0}, {313.7, 0.1}}], 
    Line[{{340.6, 0}, {340.6, 0.14}}], 
    Line[{{355.1, 0}, {355.1, 0.18}}], 
    Line[{{368.2, 0}, {368.2, 0.22}}]}];
Show[lPlot, pt, lines]
```

I got two tables, but I found it difficult to use them

```
p1Line = Partition[
  Riffle[Flatten@Table[data[[#, 1]] &[Range[Length[data]]], 1], 
   Table[0, Length[data]]], 2] 
p2Line = Partition[
  Flatten[Table[data[[#]] &[Range[Length[data]]], 1]], 2]
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Szabolcs Like somehow that the values of 'pLine1' and 'pLine2' were in the first code automatically and not manually as I did.

Comment: @JPeter You can make your plot using: `ListPlot[
 data
 , Joined -> True
 , PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Red, Point[{0, 0}]}]}
 , Epilog -> {Dashed, Line[{{#1, 0}, {#1, #2}}] & @@@ data}
 ]`

Comment: If you insist on the same form for `p1Line` and `p2Line`, `p1Line={#1,0}&@@@data`, and `p2Line=data`.

Comment: @N.J.Evans Sorry to **steal** your answer. What I did is valid or not in the community?

Comment: @LMC I'm not sure about everyone else, but it doesn't bother me at all. I didn't have the time to write up a full answer and wasn't quite sure what OP was looking for. You might add some explanation to the answer though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the comments of [N.J.Evans](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/11777/n-j-evans)

```
data = {{0, 0}, {228.9, 0.06}, {313.7, 0.10}, {340.6, 0.14}, {355.1, 
    0.18}, {368.2, 0.22}};

lPlot = ListPlot[data, Joined -> True];

pt = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point[Table[data[[#]] &[Range[Length[data]]], 1]]}];

lines = Graphics[{
    Dashed, Line[{{#1, 0}, {#1, #2}}] & @@@ data}];

Show[lPlot, pt, lines]
```

> [image]

Comment: I will try this

Comment: This is the answer that most closely approximates what I need, but it is not the best explained.

Answer (score 6):

You may do it as follows:

```
data = {{0, 0}, {228.9, 0.06}, {313.7, 0.10}, {340.6, 0.14}, {355.1, 
    0.18}, {368.2, 0.22}};
lPlot = ListPlot[data, Joined -> True];
pt = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point[Table[data[[#]] &[Range[Length[data]]], 1]]}];
lines = Graphics[{Dashed, Line /@ Transpose[{p1Line, p2Line}]}];
Show[lPlot, pt, lines]
```

Here `Transpose[{p1Line, p2Line}]` makes the job.

But you may do it in a shorter way:

```
    Show[{
  ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> Bottom, 
   FillingStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed]],
  ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Blue, Joined -> True]
}]
```

yielding this:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: @AlexiBoulbitch +1 Great use of `Filling`!

Answer (score 5):

So at first I really suggest you read how to use [Table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html). Play  with it, look how the parameters work together.

If you want to use table (and see how it works) you can look at this code:

```
lines=Graphics[Join[{Dashed},Table[Line[{data[[i]],{data[[i,1]],0}}],{i,1,Length[data]}]]];
points=Graphics[Join[{Red,PointSize[0.02]},Table[Point[data[[i]]],{i,1,Length[data]}]]];
lPlot=ListPlot[data,Joined->True];
Show[lPlot,lines,points]
```

But i would use Operators to map directly to your data
See [Map](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), [Apply](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html)
which gives us:

```
lPlot=ListPlot[data,Joined->True];
Show[lPlot,Graphics[{Red,PointSize[0.02],Point/@data,Dashed,Line[{{#1,#2},{#1,0}}]&@@@data}]]
```

In the end you can put everything in ListPlot with the Epilog-Option instead of using Show with Graphics:

```
lPlot=ListPlot[data,Joined->True,Epilog->{Red,PointSize[0.02],Point/@data,Dashed,Line[{{#1,#2},{#1,0}}]&@@@data}]
```

Comment: `Map` and `Apply` are exactly the commands that don't work as well.

Comment: I used them in my solutions in the operatorform. /@ and @@@

Answer (score 5):

A couple of points.

The use of `Table` in the following construction from your question

```
pt = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.02], 
    Point[Table[data[[#]] &[Range[Length[data]]], 1]]}];
```

is not needed. You can just use `data`.

```
pt = Graphics[
  {
   Red,
   PointSize[0.02],
   Point[data]
   }
  ]
```

To make up the lines

```
{
 Line[{{0,     0}, {0,        0}}],
 Line[{{228.9, 0}, {228.9, 0.06}}],
 Line[{{313.7, 0}, {313.7,  0.1}}], 
 Line[{{340.6, 0}, {340.6, 0.14}}],
 Line[{{355.1, 0}, {355.1, 0.18}}],
 Line[{{368.2, 0}, {368.2, 0.22}}]
 }
```

you can use

```
Map[Line[{{#[[1]], 0}, #}] &, data]
```

or if you prefer `Table`

```
Table[
 Line[{{dataPt[[1]], 0}, dataPt}],
 {dataPt, data}
 ]
```

It is a matter of choice whether you want to use a symbol name for these constructions and then use the symbol in `Graphics` or use the constructions directly. Here I will use it directly.

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data, Joined -> True],
 Graphics[
  {
   Dashed,
   Map[Line[{{#[[1]], 0}, #}] &, data[[2 ;; -1]]],
   Red,
   PointSize[0.02],
   Point[data]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

**Using `Mesh` and `Projection`:**

```
data = {{0, 0}, {228.9, 0.06}, {313.7, 0.10}, {340.6, 0.14}, {355.1, 
    0.18}, {368.2, 0.22}};

ListLinePlot[data
 , Mesh -> All
 , MeshStyle -> Red
 , Epilog -> {Dashed
   , Line[{#, Projection[#, {1, 0}]}] & /@ data
   }
 ]
```

---

Or the `Graphics` approach only.

```
Graphics[{
  ColorData[97][1], Line@data
  , Black, Dashed
  , Line[{#, Projection[#, {1, 0}]}] & /@ data
  , Red, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point@data
  }
 , AspectRatio -> 1/2 (* Can you plot without it? *)
 , Axes -> True
 ]
```

---

*Result:*

[image]